# StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception

```
    2012-03-23 10:42:08 StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for      servlet jsp threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.TitleFrame_jsp._jspService(TitleFrame_jsp.java:66)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:311)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:301)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:248)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:204)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:245)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:184)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:972)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:206)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:833)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:732)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:619)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:688)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:536)
```

How to resolve this error?

Whenever i am getting this error i have to restart tomcat.
and i dont want to restart tomcat
can any give me the proper solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the bug in TitleFrame.jsp. Something is null where you are assuming that it is not.

You can look in Tomcat's work directory for the TitleFrame_jsp.java file and the problem will be on line 66 of that file. You should be able to map that back easily to the relevant line in your jsp.

Comment: Thanks Mark Thomas I know that but problem with that line i am not able to get the solution. Here is that line 66:           String     sShowLanguage = session.getAttribute("showlanguage").toString();             it is problem realted to some session.getAttribute

Comment: I suspect that the session attribute showlanguage does not exist.